# Publishing multi-module to maven central

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

my project originally had just one root project with the src folder and the publishing worked fine. Now I added a new module to the project and I wanna include that in the publishing to. The module has a different group id. I tried this: https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/http-interactions/build.gradle.kts
But this just won't work. Anyone got an idea for that?
The module Http-Interactions is that I wanna include

Comment: When I try: :Http-Interactions:publishToMavenLocal I always get "UP-TO-DATE"

Comment: Okay I needed to replace withType with create in the publications scope.
I now see a folder in maven local right next to the main dependency but I can't import it. In the dependency it's missing a .module file, a javadoc file and a source file, but the main dependency is how it should be.

Comment: also the dependencies in the pom file are missing

Comment: nvm the javadoc is there but there is no jar with the actual thing